# DataStage - catch a failure message into sql table

Tags: error-handling, datastage

I want to run DATASTAGE process and catch the error message if the process is failed.
Then insert it into errors_table on my sql database.

any advice?

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of errors you want to catch?

Comment: any failure message I get when the job is failed. 
the main goal of the question is to insert into  error table a value in ERROR_MSG column .

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DSODB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.monitor.doc/topics/odb.html) (DataStage Operations Database)

It is already a datamodel and the JOBRUNLOG table will already have the data you are looking for.

There is also lots of other valuable information which can be accessed via the Operations Console (Web Frontend) or just SQL as you like.

You can download a graphical data modell of the DSODB [here](https://www.ids-system.de/downloads)